# php mvc can't find css sheet because of ending slashes in url

Tags: php, css

I just ran into a weird problem that I hope someone can help me with.
Well, im using a mvc framework with my php project (first time), but it can't locate my css stylesheet from the different views if the URL is ending with a "normal slash" (/).

I have a Bootstrap class for handling this (deleting ending slashes):

```
$url = isset($_GET ['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$url = rtrim ( $url, '/');
$url = explode ( '/', $url );
```

But this doesn't seem to help regarding the stylesheet. The weird part is, when I try to print out $url, it doesn't have slash at the end, but still my views can't find it when there is one or more slashes in the end..

I found a "solution" if there is one slash at the end

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>'.$title.'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

But then if my url has 2 slashes (help//) it doesn't work.
Adding "../" before the path to the css sheet is a bad solution.. does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to REALLY trim the slashes from the $url?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this has **NOTHING** do do with MVC architectural design pattern

Comment: no I guess your'e right.. i just figured that the mvc pattern could be the cause of this problem. sorry for misleading you

Comment: what's probably causing problems is either confusion about your own directory structure or something wrong in .htaccess file (assuming you are on apache). Also, using relative paths for CSS/JS/images is a really bad idea: it prevents caching.

Comment: I am not sure what it is, but here you can see my dir structure:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2_2oeJkE3xAakR4NER1ZkJrZVk/edit?usp=drive_web
It is the header.php that can't find my css file, unless I add "../" in fornt of the path. Did this clear something up? And yes im on apache

Comment: my .htaccess file contains only this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Use absolute paths (ones that begin with /). That should solve your routing-related problems.

Comment: I im trying to use an absolute path, be the css file still can't be found.. How would you say the path should look like if i want to access public/css/stylesheet.css from my header.php?

Comment: Ok i figured it out now.. i've made a constant with define() in php and used that in front of my path public/css/stylesheet.css.. If anyone should be interested. Thanks for your help though teresko